# ROS Answers SE migration: rosbag play

Tags: ros, bagfile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I record a topic with rosbag record topic and I could play the bag file. The topic I record was only published for example every five seconds, but when I play the bag file the topic was not published with the same time, but much shorter. Can I change this? I need the same break/time between topic publish and next topic publish which I had when I record this.

Thanks for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63923/rosbag-play/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-05-29

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosbag usually plays back at the speed it recieved data.  If you can show a way to reproduce this it may be a bug, but it is designed to do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0